# How to remove default close button in RadDesktopAlert control of telerik for wpf, is this possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

How to remove the default close button in `RadDesktopAlert` control of telerik for WPF, is this possible?

My code is below:

```
public RadDesktopAlertManager ExecuteBatchDesktopAlert=new RadDesktopAlertManager(AlertScreenPosition.BottomRight,new Point(5,5),5);

public void ShowNotification(string header, string content)
{
    var radAlert = new RadDesktopAlert
    {                
        Header = header,
        Content = content,
        Height = 90,
        Width = 300,
        Opacity = 1,
        Background = Brushes.Gray,

    };
    ExecuteBatchDesktopAlert.ShowAlert(radAlert);            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach that I take to any of the RadControls is to redefine the style in my application overwriting the style created by Telerik.  In this case I would define a style in the `App.xaml` in the section `<Application.Resources>` section.

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadDesktopAlert">
....
</Style>
```

This will overwrite the style for each case the control is used.  You can limit the scope of the change by redefining the style in the Window/Page/UserControl closest to where it is used.

Now the style provided from Telerik is likely to be fairly complicated.  So as a starting point copy the style from the Telerik Theme you are interested in.  You can typically find these in the following location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for WPF ....\Themes.Implicit\...`.

From a quick look it is held in the `Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml`

Copy the style itself to your `App.xaml` and the linked styles or control templates from this file and just remove the close button.